# How to use weights in tf.metrics.auc?

Tags: tensorflow, auc

The docs for the [tf.metrics.auc function in tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) say

> weights: Optional Tensor whose rank is either 0, or the same rank as labels, and must be broadcastable to labels (i.e., all dimensions must be either 1, or the same as the corresponding labels dimension).

and

> If weights is None, weights default to 1. Use weights of 0 to mask values.

Suppose I want to use the weights to measure two AUCs: one for men, one for women.

Can you give an example of how to do that?

**EDIT**: And suppose I have enough classes that I don't want to divide the data into all the different classes, and enough data that I don't want to read it all into memory.  That is, I want to do it in a streaming fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your labels are a vector, setting the weights to be a vector with 1 for rows where data points belong to a class and 0 for rows where data points do not belong to that class will let you compute AUC for members of that class.

Comment: I understood the theory. I was looking for a practical example with code. I figured something out, maybe I'll post it.